# Как упростить код Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Народ, посоветуйте плиз как можно упростить следующий код, сделать его красивым.

```
$(".qq_80").text("Минимальное количество символов 40. Вы ввели "+count_letters).slideDown(function(){
    var t=this;
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(t).slideUp();
    }, 3000)
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Выстроить в цепочку вызовов в стиле jQuery. Для задержки дальнейшего выполнения вместо `setTimeout()` можно использовать родной `.delay()` от jQuery:

```js
var $el = $(".qq_80")
  ,count_letters = 12
  ,txt = "Минимальное количество символов 40. Вы ввели " + count_letters 
;

$el.text(txt).hide().slideDown().delay(3e3).slideUp();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qq_80">Ololo</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А где можно почитать про сокращения времени 3e3?

Comment: Почитайте про [числа в JavaScript](https://learn.javascript.ru/number). `3e3` это «научная» или экспоненциальная форма: `3 * 10-в-степени-3`. Так короче записывать числа, оканчивающиеся на нули, напр., 5 млрд. будет `5e9`